# Stack overflow when formatting a slice

Tags: rust

I've a simple implementation of the `std::fmt::Display` trait. The error I get running it:

```
thread 'main' has overflowed its stack
fatal runtime error: stack overflow
[1]    1015774 abort (core dumped)  vismut init
```

There's probably something obvious wrong with it but I've never seen an error like that with code like this so I'm a bit confused.

Link to [Rust Playground with the code below](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=41156b8d84e2f0584849c41eaba004a1).

```
use std::fmt::{Formatter, Display};

pub enum MyOptions {
    First,
    Second,
    Third,
}

impl Display for MyOptions {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", &self.to_string()[1..])
    }
}

fn main() {
    assert!(format!("{}", MyOptions::First).eq("irst"))
}
```

Comment: By default, enums can't be converted to a string. You can use the `strum` crate to conveniently implement this conversion.

Comment: Its worth pointing out that clippy has a [lint](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#to_string_in_display) that can detect this issue in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`to_string`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html)'s default implementation is based on the `Display` trait.

This means here that the `fmt` function calls itself. This makes the call stack explode.

The simplest solution here would be to explicitly match on variants in your implementation:

```rust
impl Display for MyOptions {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        match self {
            Self::First => write!(f, "irst"),
            Self::Second => write!(f, "econd"),
            Self::Third => write!(f, "hird"),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah god damn it. This is what happens when you let the IDE show you what functions are available. Thank you!